# how to find only large peaks in waves in `matplotlib`

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to find peaks in my waves, but I capture smaller peaks, while I just need large ones.

I tried some code to find the peaks but it's not that accurate.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    # Generate a noisy AR(1) sample
    #np.random.seed(1)
    rs = np.linspace(1259,1650,4768)
    xs = [0]

    af = pd.read_csv("/home/pi/Downloads/newdata2.csv")

    sr = list(af.hex)

    for r in sr:
        xs.append(r)
    df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns=['data'])

    # Find local peaks
    df['min'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(10) > df.data) & 
    (df.data.shift(-10) > df.data)]

    df['max'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) < df.data) & 
    (df.data.shift(-1) < df.data)]

    # Plot results
    #plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r') # this is valley
     plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')
     df.data.plot()
     plt.savefig('graph.png')
     plt.show()
```

I want to find large peaks only.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28uxT.png)

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data ([minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: my data is a frequency and power the 4768 values in one column

Comment: you can give me answer on also sine wave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking if the point is 5x (adjust this number as necessary) larger than the adjacent points.

```
df['max'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(10)*5 < df.data) & 
    (df.data.shift(-10)*5 < df.data)]
```

Comment: the peaks are increased more when i tries 5x . i just want 3 peaks of top of graph Arienrhod

Comment: I've modified my solution to check the points a bit further away. it works on the sine wave (without 5x, b/c of the y-lim of the sine wave).

Comment: the peaks is covers all wave

Comment: i just need top 3 peaks

Comment: I can't help you w/o the data.

Comment: how can i send you the data?

Comment: give me email address i will mail you the data

Comment: edit your post and provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: data is too large cant add . if you provide mail . i'll mail you the data

Comment: Check the link I've added to your question on how to add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: ya i saw that link but its only for the 30000 characters . i uploaded about 1.2 lac

Comment: sushants367@gmail.com is my email. just ping me with hi

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `find_peaks` from `scipy`.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.signal import find_peaks

    x = np.array(1400 - 0.002 * np.linspace(0,700_000,700_000))
    # add peaks 100 - 150 units high
    for i in range(70_000,630_000,70_000):
        x[i] += np.random.rand()*50+100

    peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, threshold=100)
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you  for help but i want to find peaks in data wave is like any value or peak i can increase with 150 units up Axois